# Passing Id from ashx page to aspx lable or hidden field

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete, ashx

I have one textbox which which is autocomplete textbox(i.e it is binding data from database and display result on key press accordingely)

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "select (Patient_First_Name+' '+Patient_Last_Name+' '+Patient_DOB+' '+Patient_Home_Phone+' '+Patient_Account_No)as Patient_Name from PATIENT_DETAIL where " + "Patient_First_Name like @SearchText + '%' and Practice_Id in (select id from PRACTICE_DETAIL where practice_Name_Description = '" + st + "')";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
   cmd.Connection = conn;
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
   conn.Open();
   using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
       while (sdr.Read())
       {
           sb.Append(sdr["Patient_Name"]).Append(Environment.NewLine);
       }
   }
   conn.Close();
   context.Response.Write(sb.ToString()); 
}
```

Now in my table i also have Id column in each row. i want to transfer that id to my lable or hiddenfield in aspx page whenever i am selecting any result in textbox.

I think i need to do some changes inside `"while(sdr.Read())"` block, but not sure what to do.

can anyone please explain me how to do it.

Comment: I assume you are using ajax... if so your return string could be an Dictionary where key=id value=textbpxValue. Alternatively your returned string could be something like id#textboxValue. In your client you'd have to split string by the # and add values to appropriate elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally be sending the data using a DTO. Steps

First create a helper class

```
public class Patient
{
    public string PatientID { get; set; }
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
}
```

Now change your ashx code like this

```
var patients = new List<Patient>();
.....
.....
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select Patient_ID, Pateient_Name from SomeTable";
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            patients.Add(new Patient
            {
                PatientID = sdr["Patient_ID"].ToString(),
                PatientName = sdr["Patient_Name"].ToString()
            }); 
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var outputJson = serializer.Serialize(patients);
    context.Response.Write(outputJson);
}
```

This will give you the string output

```
[{"PatientID":"1","PatientName":"blah"},{"PatientID":"2","PatientName":"blsdsdah"}]
```

Now you need to deserlialize on aspx page. (not sure if you need it on server-side or client side)

Server Side

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var patients = serializer.Deserialize<List<Patient>>(op);
```

Client Side

```
.done(function(){
    var patients = $.parseJSON( data );
    for(var i = 0; i< patients.length; i++){
        console.log(patients[i].PatientID + " : " + patients[i].PatientName);
    }
});
```